# ActiveMQ web console isn't working

Tags: activemq-classic, web-console

My activeMQ is starting, communicating with Database but when I try to access the WEB console "connection refused". Any ideas, please...

PS: These are the only messages reported on startup:

```
 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@39aeed2f:  root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@58cbafc2) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 | INFO  | Database adapter driver override recognized for : [mysql_connector_java] - adapter: class org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.MySqlJDBCAdapter | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does your ActiveMQ config even start Jetty? That is - include jetty.xml ?

Comment: the Jetty.xml is configured as well...

Comment: <bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
             <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
        <property name="host" value="IP"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
    </bean>

Comment: from activemq.xml I call jetty.xml      <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

Comment: You are not giving enough context to be able to answer the question. Connection refused suggest that there is no jetty on port 8161. You should see `ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/` in your log-file. If your only log message is what you posted, you need to be a lot more specific in your question.

Comment: Sorry Petter. When I start I can see just     INFO: Loading '/app/apache-activemq-5.15.1//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/app/apache-activemq-5.15.1//data/activemq.pid' (pid '5144')

Comment: I changed the activeMQ version. replaced the configurations of database and access!!! And now ActiveMQ web console does not work!! There something in ENV file to do?

Comment: Petter, when I removed the DB config in activemq.xml web console worked again!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because we had more than 1 server with the same DataBase configuration in activemq.xml. Web console appears only for master servers, the slave blocks its jetty server to start when grabbing the lock of the database.

Comment: Yes, this is a weird behavior from the console when the instance is slave, it shows `Exception occurred while processing this request,` while it would be better to say "I am in slave mode".